Quarkus Create Project Build issue
I have JDK 11 & Apache Maven 3.9.9. I'm trying to run the Maven command given below:
mvn -U io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:create   -DprojectGroupId=org.agoncal.quarkus.starting  -DprojectArtifactId=rest-book -DclassName="org.agoncal.quarkus.starting.BookResource"  -Dpath="/api/books"  -Dextensions="resteasy-jsonb" 

Getting this build error after running the above Maven command:
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.14.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
        Failed to read artifact descriptor for io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:jar:3.14.4
 @ 
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: The following artifacts could not be resolved: io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom:pom:3.14.4 (absent): Could not transfer artifact io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom:pom:3.14.4 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target @ line 22, column 25
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-jsonb:jar is missing. @ line 33, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-arc:jar is missing. @ line 37, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-rest:jar is missing. @ line 41, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5:jar is missing. @ line 45, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.rest-assured:rest-assured:jar is missing. @ line 50, column 21
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.agoncal.quarkus.starting:rest-book:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\223099871.HCAD\Downloads\rest-book (1)\rest-book\pom.xml) has 7 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.14.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
[ERROR]         Failed to read artifact descriptor for io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:jar:3.14.4
[ERROR]     -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: The following artifacts could not be resolved: io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom:pom:3.14.4 (absent): Could not transfer artifact io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom:pom:3.14.4 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target @ line 22, column 25 -> [Help 3]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-jsonb:jar is missing. @ line 33, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-arc:jar is missing. @ line 37, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-rest:jar is missing. @ line 41, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5:jar is missing. @ line 45, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.rest-assured:rest-assured:jar is missing. @ line 50, column 21
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException
[ERROR] [Help 3] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

I tried with curl and set up Jbang as well.

Not sure if that's relevant or not, but Quarkus requires Java 17 since version 3.7, so I'd try upgrading your JDK first.
